# ldap integration in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on integrating ruby with ldap. And it's working fine.

Created `test.com` in ldap and I can bind with it successfully.

Then I created a new organizational unit `company`. Under company there are some `users`

Now I want to bind with the `users(authentication)` under `company` organizational unit.

I can access the user using `Filter.eq`

But I want to bind with the users.
Suggestions plz..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using "activeldap" gem you could do this (in your Model):

```
ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'cn', :prefix => 'ou=company', :classes => ['inetOrgPerson']
```

So now you can instantiate users by "cn" and then authenticate by whatever password field you have defined.